# Iterate over all Links in the Dom - Is there a more elegant solution?

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick, ontouch

I am looping over all  elements on my page which is handled by pushState and preventing default behaviour. I assume my function is pretty expensive, so I tried different other solutions with eventlisteners which did not work as expected. This function is running on each link click after the readystate event of that *xhr* request. In the end I am changing the content of my  element by *xhr* and run this function again.

I also tried to do it like this: https://gomakethings.com/why-event-delegation-is-a-better-way-to-listen-for-events-in-vanilla-js/

which adds a single listeners which looks where you clicked, but this end up showing me other elements I clicked and not my a-elements so this didn't work either.

```
var dragging = false;

function addPushStateActionToAllLinks() {

    var e = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));

    for ( var i = 0; i < e.length; i++ ) {

        e[i].ontouchmove = function () {
            dragging = true;
        };

        e[i].ontouchstart = function () {
            dragging = false;
        };

        e[i].onclick = function ( el ) {
            el.preventDefault ? el.preventDefault() : (el.returnValue = false);
        };

        if(e[i].getAttribute('rel') !== 'noopener noreferrer' && e[i].getAttribute('href') != "" ) {
            e[i].ontouchend = function ( el ) {
                if ( dragging === true ) {
                    return;
                }
                loadInternalLinkByXhr( this, true );
                el.preventDefault ? el.preventDefault() : (el.returnValue = false);
             };
        } else {
            e[i].ontouchend = function ( el ) {
                if ( dragging === true ) {
                  return;
                }
                loadExternalLink( this );
                el.preventDefault ? el.preventDefault() : (el.returnValue = false);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
I also tried this, works as expected but i assume click is slower on mobile devices:

```
function someFunction( ) {

    var e = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for ( var i = 0; i < e.length; i++ ) {

        if(e[i].getAttribute('rel') !== 'noopener noreferrer' && e[i].getAttribute('href') != "" ) {

            e[i].onclick = function ( el ) {
                if(typeof window.navigator.vibrate !== 'undefined') {
                    window.navigator.vibrate( 1 );
                }
                loadInternalLinkByXhr( this, true );
                el.preventDefault ? el.preventDefault() : (el.returnValue = false);
             };
        } else {
            e[i].onclick = function ( el ) {
                if(typeof window.navigator.vibrate !== 'undefined') {
                    window.navigator.vibrate( 1 );
                }
                loadExternalLink( this );
                el.preventDefault ? el.preventDefault() : (el.returnValue = false);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I want the most performant best practice for doing this. Only parts of my site is changing when you click a link, navigation, header etc. stay like they are. I tried adding eventlisteners to each element and it end up firing multiple *xhr* requests which got more and more and I was unable to figure out why this happens, I also tried removing the eventlistener before adding a new, but it still seemed to add multiple to it. This only worked on full page-requests for me, which I want to prevent. However, my function works as expected, before I was using onclick only, now I am trying ontouchend with move prevention because it might react a tiny bit faster. This project is new, so I am open to modern browser features and vanilla js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single function for each event without duplicating them if you use function declarations in your original design.

```
function ontouchmove  () {
   dragging = true;
};

function ontouchstart() {
    dragging = false;
};

function onclick( el ) {
    el.preventDefault ? el.preventDefault() : (el.returnValue = false);
};



for ( var i = 0; i < e.length; i++ ) {

        e[i].ontouchmove = ontouchmove;

        e[i].ontouchstart ontouchstart;

        e[i].onclick = onclick;

        if(e[i].getAttribute('rel') !== 'noopener noreferrer' && e[i].getAttribute('href') != "" ) {
            e[i].ontouchend = function ( el ) {
                if ( dragging === true ) {
                    return;
                }
                loadInternalLinkByXhr( this, true );
                el.preventDefault ? el.preventDefault() : (el.returnValue = false);
             };
        } else {
            e[i].ontouchend = function ( el ) {
                if ( dragging === true ) {
                  return;
                }
                loadExternalLink( this );
                el.preventDefault ? el.preventDefault() : (el.returnValue = false);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

---

Else, using JQuery to select all your elements at once and setting the event on the whole selection makes better sense.

```
var allLinks = $('a');

allLinks.on('touchmove', function () {
     dragging = true;
};)


allLinks.on('touchstart', function () {
     dragging = false;
};)


allLinks.on('cick', function () {
     this.preventDefault ? this.preventDefault() : (this.returnValue = false);
};)
```

You can use `.each` method to iterate your selection and perform actions based on attributes.

```
allLinks.each(function() {

   if ($(this).attr('rel') !== 'noopener noreferrer' && $(this).attr('href') != "" ){
       ...
   }

});
```

Comment: Hm, adding JQuery is heavy weight for my "as light as possible and as fast as possible mobile-website".... just for one thing to do. I want to continue on Vanilla JavaScript which also makes me a better coder, the learning curve is huge.

Comment: The first part of the answer makes a jquery-less suggestion. I highlighted it in the edit.

Comment: This gives me log entries in chrome:

Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event.....

Comment: What is the log entry?

Comment: [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See <URL>

Comment: i edited the above and add another version of mine, works as expected, but thats slower, right?

Comment: It cannot be slower. The whole passive listener concept is about better performance. Compared this to your original code, 100 elements will create 100 different function instances per event. We can handle the event with just 1 function instance than 100.

Comment: i actually cannot follow you. Which code you re talking about? That in initially added or my edit? Or yours? I dont get it, your code also adds "ontouchend" to all <a> elements.

Comment: Yes. but my code has a single function per event gandler whereas your method creates as much functions as the links.

Comment: right, but how to get rid of those console violation messages then?

Comment: Please follow the link closely. It can help you getting rid of the warnng